# Prevent Image Capture from opening when a memory card is inserted

Tags: macos, sd-card, image-capture

Every time I plug in a SD memory card, Image Capture launches, is there a way to disable this? I am running OS X Mavericks.

Comment: The real answer is to click on the very tiny triangle of in the bottom left corner (looks like ejection icon) and then it will bring up a menu, where you can select the default action to open the device with "no application." This has been a discussion for sometime now. Bad UI design on Apple's part. Hopefully something will change soon.

Answer (score -1):

Your Mac doesn't really know the difference between a Camera and the SD card. It treats them all pretty much the same. So, in the iPhoto Preferences you can select 'Do Nothing' when a camera is connected, and that will stop Image Capture launching.

iPhoto Menu -> Preferences -> General